Does Calcium Sulfide Emit UV Light via Phosphorescence?
In this presentation by Niewenglowski at the French academy of science in 1896, there is a report of a photographic plate being darkened after being next to calcium sulfide that was exposed to sunlight. This is one of the papers that Henri Becquerel mentions as his inspiration for the experiment that led him to discover radioactivity.
Since the paper is in French, here is my translation of the beginning of it:

I noticed that phosphorescent bodies have similar properties towards sunlight as zinc sulfide has with Röntgen rays as they make them able to go through some bodies that would absorb them, a property that M. Charles Henry reported on during last session:
An ordinary photographic plate being wrapped in several sheets of black or red paper, I placed two coins on top, and I covered one of the half with a glass plate covered with phosphorescent powder (calcium sulfide) ; after four to five hours in sunlight, the half that had received direct sunlight was intact and bore no traces of the coin on top of it, showing that light did not go through the red or black paper ; the half that was receiving sunlight through the phosphorescent plate had become completely black, except for the part corresponding to the coin, creating a white-on-black silhouette.

I am a bit surprised by this result: at that time everybody was experimenting with X rays, and X rays can go through dark paper, but how can you produce X rays with just sunlight?
Later in the same paper, Niewenglowski mentions the possibility of pressure causing artefacts in this type of experiments, as in if the coin presses against the photographic plate it could cause an imprimpt, but he seems to say he was very careful about avoiding this.
So I was thinking maybe calcium sulfide emits UV light through phosphorescence? And maybe the black paper that Niewenglowski used maybe was opaque to visible light but not to the exact wavelength produced by the phosphorecent calcium sulfide.
